# How to show Hash-Then-Encrypt is not AE-secure

Tags: authenticated-encryption

[image](E,D) is a CPA-secure cipher defined over (K,M,C).H: C → T is collision resistant hash functions.
E(k,m):=E(k,m), H(c)), D=(k,c1,c2):=D(k,c1) if H(c1)==C2 otherwise Reject.

ps:the question is from the book  <A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography[Boneh]> exercise 9.2
can use cpa and cca to proof

Comment: Hint: Can you somehow modify a ciphertext and make the changed one be accepted?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, what you're describing is Encrypt-then-Hash.

Comment: It's a bit hard to read, I think something got lost in translation. C2 seems to be the authentication tag? Strange variable name, C was the input to the hash before, and is likely the ciphertext (?).

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad English. I have upload the picture of the problem. I aggre with the second comment , but I don't know how to show it use cca or cpa.

Comment: first one  is simple as $H_1{(m)}$ leaks the information about the message in the ciphertext. So it is not CPA secure.

Comment: In second one , the scheme will be under CCA. as @SEJPM mentioned attacker can modify the c1 such that new ciphertext c2 will be the result of ${H_2(c1)=c2}$, so ciphertext integrity is not preserved, required in AE.

Comment: in second one.In my view, it if just change C1 and let c2=H2(c1), the ciphertext(c1,c2) could pass the first "if". and then it will calculate  D(k,c1), c1 is changed, it might be not legal ciphertext.It means input changed (c1,c2),can't output readable message

Answer (score 1):

- first one is simple as ${H_1(m)}$ leaks the information about the message in the ciphertext. So it is not CPA secure.
- second one , the scheme will be under CCA. as @SEJPM mentioned attacker can modify the c1 such that new ciphertext c2 will be the result of ${H_2(c1)=c2}$, so ciphertext integrity is not preserved, required in AE.

Comment: in second one.In my view, it if just change C1 and let c2=H2(c1), the ciphertext(c1,c2) could pass the first "if". and then it will calculate D(k,c1), c1 is changed, it might be not legal ciphertext.It means input changed (c1,c2),can't output readable message

Comment: yes, right. Here,  ${H_2}$  doesn't seem to be not one-way function. we know that ${H_2^{-1}(c_2)=c_1}$,  we have both value (c1,c2) then ${H_2}$ is a function C to C. ${H_2:C--> C}$.

Comment: We have two things , (E,D) a CPA-secure cipher and a Hash function. consider m1 is having same length as single block of CBC mode. once Attacker receives the ${c_1}$ along with IV 
it will modify IV as ${IV \oplus 1}$ , this new ${c_1}'$ will be given to Hash function to get ${c_2}'$. now 
modified ${c_1}$ will be given for decryption and he will receive ${m_1 \oplus 1}$ .

Comment: got it, thank you very much